# Why is my date_field parameter nested inside the label name?

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4

in my controller, I have this:

```
  def index
    filter = []

    if !params[:paid].blank?
      paid = params[:paid]
      filter << ["copay_received = '#{paid.to_s}'"]
    end

    if !params[:junk].blank?
      junk = params[:junk][:effective_on]
      filter << ["clients.effective_on >= '#{junk.to_s}'"]
    end 

    @unpaids = Appointment.joins(:client).where(filter.join(" AND "))   

  end
```

which is based on the (non-accepted) answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703231/building-a-rails-form-to-filter-an-index-page).

Here is the form I used on the index page to search it:

```
<%= form_tag("/", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:paid, "Search for:") %>
  <%= check_box_tag(:paid) %>
  <%= date_field(:junk, :effective_on) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

I finally got my date_field working (as shown with the effective_on parameter).

But my question is why do I have to go an extra layer down into the params hash to get `:effective_on` while I don't have to do the same thing to reach `:paid`?

Comment: `date_field()` is a new helper in Ruby on Rails 4.0, what's version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using the wrong method. it should be `date_field_tag`.

the `date_field` method is supposed to be used with an object form like

```
form_for @user do |f|
  f.date_field :born_on
end
```

Comment: so which part is missing?

Comment: why does date_field work the way that it does? In what sense exactly is it wrong if it works by going one layer deeper into the hash? What did I do differently from this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#other-helpers-of-interest ?

Comment: you did not do anything different. the example output shows that those will be nested `user[born_on]`. it's just not a good example as those helpers should be used with objects in forms.

Comment: so I take it then that "tags" are used without objects with the corresponding tag-less field are for use with ActiveRecord objects?

Comment: yes, that is exactly the case! the thing is: you don't have to use it that way :)